# MEF and MVVM - way to add conventions?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, dependency-injection, mef

Is there a way to hook into the internals of CompositionContainer?

For example, let's say any time an import is called on a export ending with the word "View" I might want to inject an export ending with "ViewModel" into its DataContext.

Is there a way to do that?  I'm trying to avoid code like this in every View:

```
    [Export("MainView")]
    public partial class MainView : Window
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MainView([Import("MainViewModel")] dynamic viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
```

Would be nice to simplify to just this, and use conventions:

```
        [Export("MainView")]
        public partial class MainView : Window
        {
            public MainView()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So far best I've come up with is to use an IViewLocator service that does this work, then always use it for importing views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some folks working on this, including the Mef team apparently :) 
Here is a blog post you might find interesting:

http://thecodejunkie.com/2010/03/bringing-convention-based-registration.html

And here is another slightly less detailed one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2011/03/08/mef-s-convention-model.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you are looking for a library  or framework which can reduce your effort.

Please have a look at library [WPF Application framework](http://waf.codeplex.com/). I am using it very well.